# How to count the number of column values in sql group by hours?

Tags: mysql

The original table is

```
+---------------------+--------------+
| InputTime           | Species      |
+---------------------+--------------+
| 2021-06-21 14:00:23 | Burr         |
| 2021-06-21 14:00:23 | Transform    |
| 2021-06-21 15:00:23 | Burr         |
| 2021-06-21 15:00:23 | Gas          |
| 2021-06-21 15:00:23 | HoleBlocked  |
| 2021-06-21 15:00:23 | Insert       |
| 2021-06-21 15:00:23 | InsertPowder |
| 2021-06-21 15:00:23 | Scr          |
| 2021-06-21 15:00:23 | Scratch      |
| 2021-06-21 15:00:23 | Unmolded     |
| 2021-06-21 16:08:20 | Burr         |
| 2021-06-21 16:08:20 | Gas          |
| 2021-06-21 16:08:20 | HoleBlocked  |
| 2021-06-21 16:08:20 | Insert       |
| 2021-06-21 16:08:20 | Scr          |
| 2021-06-21 16:08:20 | Scratch      |
| 2021-06-21 16:08:20 | Transform    |
| 2021-06-21 16:08:20 | Unmolded     |
| 2021-06-21 16:28:20 | Insert       |
| 2021-06-21 16:28:20 | InsertPowder |
+---------------------+--------------+
```

And I want to change it to this form.

```
+---------------+------------------+
| InputTime     | Burr | Transform | ....
+---------------+------------------+
| 2021-06-21 14 | 2    | 1
| 2021-06-21 15 | 2    | 1
```

How to write the species on columns and count the number of each Species by input time by Time?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Comment: Do you know what your species will be ahead of time? Will they ever change?